# Linking VS Code interactive window to running Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vscode-python

Let's say that you have two windows open in VS Code, one is a Jupyter notebook, and the other is the Python interactive window. Both are running the same kernel. Is there a way to link these two windows, so when cells are run in the notebook, the interactive window will know about the resulting variables?

I'm aware that VS Code has a Python code format that can be linked to the interactive window, and that Jupyter notebooks can be converted into this format. Is it possible to directly link a Jupyter notebook to the interactive window without first doing this conversion?

With JupyterLab the is accomplished with the New Console for Notebook command.

Comment: Apparently not yet, but there is feature request for this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4573.